# WiX: How to show the upgrade message while installing?

Tags: wix

While upgrading the product, how to prompt the user whether he wants to continue with the upgrade or not?. I tried this "Publish" element on the control Next button of the Welcome Dialog

```
<Publish Event='SpawnDialog' Value='ShowMajorUpgradeDlg'>WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED</Publish>
```

I've created the UI dialog ShowMajorUpgradeDlg, but it doesnt show the dialog even though WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED is a non-zero value. I'm also using the MajorUpgrade element so that WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED is properly initialised. 
Is there any other way or should I continue with this approach?

Comment: Is it advancing to the next dialog without showing your custom dialog? Maybe there are other actions involved that are processed before your customized action? Maybe you can add the `Order="1"`-attribute for testing it. Is it also not shown if you e.g. set the condition to just `1`? Do you use one of the default Wix-UIs? In my case in my WiX source file I have something like this, i.e. I have also to reference the dialog where the event should be overwritten to jump to my custom dlg: `<Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallDirDlg">NOT Installed</Publish>`

Comment: As an aside, I suggest that you consider whether your users want to be bothered with such a question. If your newer version takes features away then perhaps a side-by-side installation would be better.